# How expensive to take 80% of plastics out the ocean?

Tags: science-based, technology, physics, environment, climate

Suppose that all the world would work together to take plastic out of the ocean. Here I include microplastics, which are much harder to remove.

How expensive would it be to remove 80%  (in wheight) of the plastic from the oceans?

This would also include structural changes to prevent most plastics from entering the oceans in the future. So for example, a 100fold decrease.

I guess that this would be really expensive, maybe trillions of dollars?

Clarification: if should have added a time scale. Let’s say this has to be done within 30 years.

Comment: All that needs to be done is to stop putting plastic in the ocean. The ultraviolets from the sun and the oxygen in the air and the water will take care of the cleanup automatically. I have no idea what would be the cost of building a functional rubbish collection and disposal system in Nigeria; it probably involve large armies.

Comment: According to the following link, plastics can take hundreds or thousands of years to decompose: https://education.nationalgeographic.org/resource/microplastics/#:~:text=The%20problem%20with%20microplastics%20is,wreak%20havoc%20on%20the%20environment.

Comment: The operating phrase in the article is **can** take. The vast majority of plastic in use is polyethylene, which does not resist very long. On the other hand, the small amount of really obstinate plastic is obviously not a grave danger to anything, exactly because it is so inert chemically.

Comment: This will be highly dependent upon the removal merhods used, how fast they need to be removed, the level of acceptible environmental impact, methods used to mitigate environmental impact, among other factor.

Comment: Plastics will and do leave the ocean. They don't do it on their own, of course, and it doesn't happen quickly. The sun degrades the plastic over time, but a much larger portion of it winds up blocking the guts of sea animals, and they carry it to the bottom. This isn't a matter of just making it go away, it's a matter of collecting it faster than the sea animals. 
However, I do question why this is a worldbuilding question. It's almost on the level of "how do I stop crime?"

Comment: "...structural changes to prevent any more plastics entering the oceans in the future" - what are you thinking of here?  Short of ceasing all human use of plastics there is no plausible way to prevent damaged/discarded/abraded plastic objects ending up in waterways.  If you could, somehow, build microplastic-catching filters across every waterway that empties into the oceans then it would devastate all marine life in those areas - the cure would be much worse than the disease.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 We can always block all and any access to all open seas and oceans—then we'd mostly have to deal with microplastics in seawater. But who cares, no one will see it. Just how humankind likes it.

Comment: https://e360.yale.edu/features/tire-pollution-toxic-chemicals - tire dust is apparently a big problem. If you want to remove 99% you'll have to address tire dust

Comment: the real problem is all the plastic that has sunk and gotten incorporated into ocean sediment, the only way to clear that is dredging , which is super expensive and destructive.

Comment: @John, I suspect that the plastics that have settled into the sediment could be ignored. When the next intelligent species arises on the planet, it'll be like the iridium layer that marks the end of the dinosaurs.

Comment: @GaryWalker, thank you for the link. Based on that, we would need to eliminate rubber tires. You can't make meshes tight enough to block five-micron chunks of tire without blocking ecological pathways. This makes the cost of such an effort exceed the world economic output.

Comment: why is this tagged "climate"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A breathtaking amount of money**

The current version of the question is asking how much it would cost to remove 99% of the plastics in the world's oceans in 30 years. From this we conclude that an organized effort is being made to remove the plastics.

A plastic bag was found [in the Mariana Trench](https://www.unep.org/news-and-stories/story/single-use-plastic-has-reached-worlds-deepest-ocean-trench), 11km below the ocean's surface. According to a survey of the Pacific Ocean, [the highest levels of plastic are between 200 and 600 meters below the surface.](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2205751-plastic-pollution-found-at-every-depth-of-the-ocean-by-deep-sea-survey/) So we're not just scooping stuff off the surface, we're netting most of it below the surface. And some of it is *deep.* Let's hope that the last 1% is below the 1.5km line. Here's why:

**Let's take <s>fish</s> plastic out of the ocean**

We know that commercial fishing trawls between [240 and 1500 meters](https://www.oceanoculus.com/news-from-the-sea/too-deep-commercial-fishing). I assume it's not that hard to trawl between 0 and 240 meters, it just isn't where the fish is.

In the U.S., commercial fishing employs [approximately 1.1 million people and has 155 billion in sales](https://www.fisheries.noaa.gov/national/sustainable-fisheries/fisheries-economics-united-states). I'm using the "take fish from the water" estimates to help us understand what it would take to "take plastic from the water."

*World-wide commercial fishing costs are hard to come by. I found one article from 2018 [here](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/sciadv.aat2504), but it's numbers for the U.S. are SO FAR BELOW the government-reported numbers that I stopped reading it. Maybe in the five years between that report and today fishing profits have risen 340X. But I doubt it. To be fair, I have limited time today and only sped-read the article. I could be wrong about the conclusions it came up with.*

The U.S. isn't the largest commercial fishing nation in the world by a considerable degree, but as one might imagine, neither China nor Japan are releasing accurate data. So, as a round (and nearly irrelevant) estimate, let's 10X what the U.S. is taking in.  1.5 trillion in profits.

And if you think reported profits are scarce, *accurate reported costs are next to impossible to find.* So, let's use a common retail profit margin number: 40%. That suggests that in one year the cost of taking fish from the water commercially is about 930 billion U.S. dollars.

The last number we need is, regrettably, very subjective. An accurate assessment of the decrease in available fish in the sea [is horrifically complex](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fmars.2022.816772/full) and based on far too many variables (although good for them for trying to account for all those variables). It doesn't help that the issue is terribly politicized, with advocates of fish-baby-fish showing the world replete with fish and advocates of we're-doomed! showing the world about to lose every fish in the ocean. In a sense, they're both right to a degree, but the we're-doomed! camp is likely more accurate than the fish-baby-fish camp. Let's set the politics aside.

Heather Patterson, [writing for the Australian Fish Stocks Report](https://www.fish.gov.au/2012-Reports/Southern_Bluefin_Tuna), has the following to say about Southern Bluefin Tuna:

[image]

Roughly speaking, in 70 years we've depleted the bluefish tuna by about 95%. Close enough for government work, as they say. We need to deplete the plastic in half that time.

**Putting all that together to get an estimate that's so rough it will make angels cry**

Why did I go to all that effort? It didn't take much searching to find an estimate of [150 billion dollars](https://www.sustainableplastics.com/news/ocean-plastics-150b-problem) to "clean up ocean plastic and environmental pollution." But I think that's low. Really low. Worse, if you read that article, there's a lot more going on with that 150 billion than just pulling plastic from the ocean — assuming that pulling plastic from the ocean is even on their list of things to do.

So my goal was to come up with a way to rationalize a number. I used the world-wide commercial fishing industry to model the idea. It's rough. Really rough. And I'm sure there are people who can poke holes in the idea (not a bad thing, if it leads to a more accurate result). But what I came up with was this:

**\$1.86 trillion U.S. dollars.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is really the kind of answer I was looking for. So now I was thinking, wouldn’t removing plastic be much more expensive than the fishing industry? After all, the fishing industry never has to catch microfish from the bottom of the ocean.

Comment: On the other hand, the bacteria from Trevor’s answer could potentially make things easier. But I don’t know if this would but be fully scalable within 30 years…

Comment: Then finally, stopping to put plastic in the ocean could also be more expensive than a trillion?

Comment: Fish depletion is not a good model for plastic depletion, because fish in the sea reproduce themselves and plastic in the sea does not.

Comment: @Riemann There will come a point where practicality overwhelms good intentions. Microplastic contamination would be impossible to remove in any significant amounts (filtering the entire ocean is a bit beyond believable tech).

Comment: @MikeScott Yes and no. I thought about that as I was driving to work after posting the answer and forgot to return to post an update. The OP doesn't say, but we make the assumption that if we're cleaning the ocean, we've stopped dumping in it. If that assumption is wrong, then the fishing model is more accurate. If the assumption is right, then the amount is pessimistic... but I very much doubt it's far off. Ultimately (IMO), the fishing model works because it's based on the consumptive demand for fish, not the ability of fish to reproduce. But it was also all I could come up with.

Comment: Does this mean that removing 99% of plastics is unrealistic, and this should be replaced with a lower percentage? And then even for that lower percentage, it costs trillions of dollars?

Comment: @Riemann Oh, it's *completely* unrealistic. Not just a little bit - a lot o' bit. 85% might, maybe, be realistic. The problem is that I don't know the percentage of macro plastics (scooped with nets) and what percentage is micro plastics (would have to be filtered), but the moment you shift from nets to filters you've crossed a believability line. There's no practical way at any technological level to keep the filtered ocean from mixing again with the unfiltered ocean. (And this assumes either perfect recycling or prohibited plastics manufacturing.)

Answer (score 9):

Just do nothing, stop putting the plastic in.
We already have plastic eating bacteria.  And radiation eating fungus.  The Earth is trying to fix itself from our mess.  Just let it do it's thing.
https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2023/sep/28/plastic-eating-bacteria-enzyme-recycling-waste

> In 2001, a group of Japanese scientists made a startling discovery at
> a rubbish dump. In trenches packed with dirt and waste, they found a
> slimy film of bacteria that had been happily chewing through plastic
> bottles, toys and other bric-a-brac. As they broke down the trash, the
> bacteria harvested the carbon in the plastic for energy, which they
> used to grow, move and divide into even more plastic-hungry bacteria.
> Even if not in quite the hand-to-mouth-to-stomach way we normally
> understand it, the bacteria were eating the plastic.

...

> What Oda and his colleagues found in that rubbish dump had never been
> seen before. They had hoped to discover some micro-organism that had
> evolved a simple way to attack the surface of plastic. But these
> bacteria were doing much more than that – they appeared to be breaking
> down plastic fully and processing it into basic nutrients. From our
> vantage point, hyperaware of the scale of plastic pollution, the
> potential of this discovery seems obvious. But back in 2001 – still
> three years before the term “microplastic” even came into use – it was
> “not considered a topic of great interest”, Oda said. The preliminary
> papers on the bacteria his team put together were never published.

...

> Fortunately, over the past four decades, scientists have become
> remarkably proficient at engineering and manipulating enzymes. When it
> comes to plastic chewing, “the Ideonella enzyme is actually very early
> in its evolutionary development”, says Andy Pickford, a professor of
> molecular biophysics at the University of Portsmouth. It is the goal
> of human scientists to take it the rest of the way.
>
> When any living organism wishes to break down a larger compound –
> whether a string of DNA, or a complex sugar, or plastic – they turn to
> enzymes, tiny molecular machines within a cell, specialised for that
> task. Enzymes work by helping chemical reactions happen at a
> microscopic scale, sometimes forcing reactive atoms closer together to
> bind them, or twisting complex molecules at specific points to make
> them weaker and more likely to break apart.
>
> If you want to improve natural enzyme performance, there are
> approaches that work in almost every case. Chemical reactions tend to
> work better at higher temperatures, for instance (this is why, if you
> want to make a cake, it is better to set the oven at 180C rather than
> 50C); but most enzymes are most stable at the ambient temperature of
> the organism they work in – 37C in the case of humans. By rewriting
> the DNA that codes an enzyme, scientists can tweak its structure and
> function, making it more stable at higher temperatures, say, which
> helps it work faster.

Throw money at this project.  And we know the world can.  Covid was the most expensive and rapidly developed cure ever.  Throw covid money at the plastic problem and it will be solved in a few years.

Comment: "stop putting the plastic in" While this made sense on first read, I later discovered that most of the plastic was created by our fishing industry. I suppose we could stop fishing.

Comment: Maybe “stop putting the plastic in” would be much more expensive than the “covid money”?

Comment: @Robert Rapplean I thought most plastic waste was create by the packaging industry. Do you have a source?

Comment: Look up the Great Pacific Garbage Patch. Some info: https://theoceancleanup.com/great-pacific-garbage-patch/

Comment: And: [More than 90% of identifiable trash in North Pacific Garbage Patch comes from just six countries](https://phys.org/news/2022-09-trash-north-pacific-garbage-patch.html) — not what I expected either.

Comment: We already have closed loop fishing and food production. Fishing in the ocean is kind of wasteful by comparison.

Comment: Ah, the most zen answer possible, gotta love that! :D

Comment: On the development of bacteria that eat the microplastics, the reason that the plastic is in the water is that we use it for things. I'm imagining a bacteria that aggressively eats fishing nets or, worse, blows onto the shore with sea spray and infects the rubber of our roadways. Suddenly the nets are splitting in the middle when we try to pull the fish in, and our tires disintegrate into slippery slime. Sounds like a good horror story.

Comment: @RobertRapplean I like the idea that humanity is forced to use environmentally friendly materials just to stop super bacteria evolving to consume everything we build.

Answer (score 3):

## Mankind would have to leave the planet.

Based on [a 2019 article](https://education.nationalgeographic.org/resource/great-pacific-garbage-patch-isnt-what-you-think/), 46% of the plastic in the ocean is broken fishing gear (nets, cages, oyster spacers, etc.). Another 20% (in 2019) was debris from the Japanese 2011 tsunami. If you add in the 9% (by weight) that is microplastics, there is no functional way of reducing the total plastics in the ocean by even 50% without ceasing human activity on the planet.

The problem is that, in order to stop putting plastic into the ocean, humans would have to stop using the ocean. They would have to stop living on the shores. They'd have to stop driving cars. The economic impact of that would be incalculable.

Comment: Do you mean that both A removing 50% of ocean plastic and B stopping to put plastic in the ocean are impossible without leaving the planet?

Comment: I hadn't thought about the plastics contributed due to storms. The 2011 tsumami is the largest and most famous, but every storm will wash discarded plastics through the storm drain systems into the oceans. Good catch!

Comment: @Riemann, "Impossible" is a rough threshold. Could mankind stop feeding itself from the oceans? I don't think we can. Could we stop driving cars and trucks? I don't think we can. We don't have an alternative, and it's the tires themselves that are the problem. Could mankind come up with alternative solutions for this? We're pretty clever, so it's not out of the question, but at what cost? Nothing is free. What would humanity have to give up, and who would talk them into it?

Answer (score 1):

It will cost **nothing (if you are patient)**. There is a substantial amount of energy to be liberated from plastic, and a lifeform will eventually evolve to make use of it. We may not be far off from this either. Some years ago, a bacteria was found naturally occurring in the guts of some earthworms that was capable of breaking plastics' molecular chains into much shorter chains; it wouldn't take much to go from this to decomposing them fully. What marine plastic is not decomposed in this way, will eventually be eaten by other organisms and drop to the ocean's bottom once those other organisms die, where it will be buried over time.

Preventing more plastic from entering the ocean will also happen for free, some years after producing plastic becomes uneconomical. This depends on the price and availability of oil, from which almost all plastics are made, and there is only so much sufficiently cheap oil in the world. Once it runs out, plastics will become unaffordable and will not be produced, and so eventually they will stop finding their way to the ocean too.

And eventually the last bacteria will eat the last piece of floating plastic, and the oceans will be free of plastic at no extra charge, even if we keep dumping it into them for as long as we possibly can.

Comment: The main focus of reducing our dependency on oil isn't a matter of oil shortage. It's a matter of burning it into the atmosphere. As we stop burning it, it will increase its availability for other purposes. Mankind has always thought that pollution would solve itself over time. Pollution issues, without an exception, are cases where others are harmed before the pollutant has time to go away. Not only does this make this a non-answer, but it sounds a lot like "don't worry, the baby turtles will eat it, and then it won't be a problem."

Comment: @RobertRapplean, thank you. Pollutants *always* go away. It may take longer than your lifetime, and you don't have to *like* living through it; but these are personal preferences which don't affect the underlying process.

Comment: In the majority of cases, where living through pollutants is a choice, then you are correct. Personally, I've never been impacted by the great pacific garbage patch. I'm sure that there are a lot of chemical company shareholders that were never impacted by dioxin poisoning, either. We all get to decide at what point we consider something worth our consideration and effort.

Comment: @RobertRapplean, thank you. And of course, just considering something *worth* the effort does not imply that we are *capable* of the effort required. Then being patient becomes the only decision available in practice.

Comment: Yea, the cost/benefit analysis is extreme in this case. I've had people ask me why we can't just send out automated skimmers to go collect it all, unable to wrap their head around the scale. You can't even filter it on the way in because a significant portion of it comes from the islands. This is like a big communal back yard, where nobody's going to mow it until nature forces us to take action.

Comment: @RobertRapplean, thank you. "I've had people ask me why we can't just send out automated skimmers to go collect it all" -- yes, this always makes me think: fine, so we go and collect it all *and then where do we put it?* ;)

Comment: "*Some years ago, a bacteria was found naturally occurring in the guts of some earthworms that was capable of breaking plastics' molecular chains into much shorter chains; it wouldn't take much to go from this to decomposing them fully.*" Reference?

Comment: Saw it on youtube, so Great For You, can you read between the lines? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I guess, it depends on the solution itself. Plastic is a material/resource which is useful to get recycled for production. If the "raw" of plastic somewhere is big enough it may be profitable to get into this - as some mines are profitable and others not especially. So, planning the delivery offset is key here. It may vary as hell, but the cheapest solutions work in good synchronization could win for someone who find it better to get big amount of it from, for example not very deep shelf, rather than buy some material, pay for chem-labs and for energy to produce plastic from scratch. That way of "mining" could later bring better offsets, which others could follow - hence make it cheaper and cheaper. And thus it would reduce some big amount of thrash from oceans in short, maybe a bit naive plan.

So the answer depends on the price ratio - production/recycling+delivery - which may vary quickly as geopolitics changes all the time on Earth, and I don't know this numbers right now, even for hypothetical country/company. It may be cheap enough one day to earn on it.

Answer (score 1):

It would never end, it would become a revenue stream for multiple govt entities and big business, soon be rife with corruption, and like aid to war torn countries & the third World there would never be an end to the costs because the money stops trickling down to the actual work really quickly.